# Windows Mobile emulator can't connect to network neither local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6

I've developed a small app for Windows Mobile 6. This app uses 2 databases: a sqlite db located on the mobile device and a SQL Server database located on a server (now it's on the same PC I'm programming with, a Windows 7 system).

When I developed it, I could test the app with the Windows mobile emulator integrated in Visual Studio 2008, and it was fine.

But now I've turned on this computer again to modify the project. But now I can't test it. The emulator can't connect to the SQL Server database (the error is "SQL Server does not exist or access denied").

On the SQL Server, I've created the user the app is using and it has the permission to connect (in fact, the connection works fine from some desktop applications we have developed).

On the config of the emulator, I've checked the PCMCIA option with the connected card.

I've tried too by installing a Windows 7 system on VirtualBox on other PC, but the result is the same: I can't connect with database.

If I open the Internet Explorer on the emulator, it hasn't connection.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Post your connection string and the SQL server setup? How is the device connected to network? What does "local database" mean for you? The sql DB is on the device?

Comment: Sorry, with "local" I mean to my computer (the developer one). However, I've found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly, I found the problem.

I was trying to connect by "localhost" and by "127.0.0.1"... but it only worked when I used the internal IP (192.168.1.X)